# Как убрать отступ

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, не могу никак понять как убрать отступ который образовался между **div class="content"** и **div class="footer"**. Мне кажется это из-за стиля **position**. Хотя сколько не верстал всегда пользовался этим правилом.

[Вот ссылка на сайт.](http://academy.icrp.ru/)

Comment: Если relative убрать у контента, то промежуток убирается, но весь див опускается. У вас какое-то неправильное сочетание float: left; position: relative; top: -455px; Что-то здесь надо как-то иначе сделать.

Comment: ага ок, понял, спасибо, сейчас попробую покрутить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

свойства `left` и `top` убрать везде, ширина `container` должна быть больше суммы ширины `sidebar` и `content`.

Comment: сделал немного по другому, запихнул sidebar в content